# Is it idiomatic to say "what do we say"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A post [From one side of the bridge to the other](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/134324/109190) says

> But what do we say if we want to go from one side of the bridge to the other?

I also found [lots of people use this expression](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20do%20we%20say%22).

Is it idiomatic to say that?

Comment: Your *lots of people use this expression* link isn't really meaningful, since most instances are ELL questions are from non-native speakers. I'd also point out that it's also not *really* appropriate for non-native speakers to ask *What do we say [in some specific situation]?* - it would make more sense to ask *What do **you** (native Anglophones) say in this situation?* Finally - *What do we say?* often occurs as a ***rhetorical question*** to  a child from a parent, when the the child has just requested or been given something, where the expected answer is ***Please*** or ***Thank You***

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is an idiomatic expression.

Comment: Please provide evidence to back up your answer. Someone else could answer "No, it isn't". Neither answer is helpful without reputable references or other good data (i.e. not Google search results or the like).

Comment: I think this answers the question, but it needs a little more discussion to be really helpful. Can you explain why it's idiomatic, or under what circumstances this idiom might be used as opposed to another idiom? This community generally frowns on one sentence answers (and questions), so it's always good to elaborate on your answer and find a way to teach the questioner something. You risk downvotes when you write a short answer like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "is this idiomatic" is a simple question, and I think it should get a simple answer. If something is not idiomatic, it is possible to explain why it isn't, and what is the right thing to say. If there is nothing wrong with an expression, there's nothing to say about it. Now, if any of you really thinks there is more to say, why don't you just add an answer, including what additional information you think is fitting? Thank you for your attention.